# How do I assign a random colour to links?

Tags: javascript

Just wondering why my code isn't working. Am I doing this completely wrong?

```
window.onload = function random() {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var colours = new Array("green","red","blue");
    var randomColour = colours[Math.floor(colours.length * Math.random())];
    for (a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
        links[a].style.color = 'randomColour';
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`'randomColor'` -> `randomColor`.
Use a variable instead of a quoted string. Also, to ensure that each link gets a random color, generate the color in the loop:

```
for (var a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
    var randomColour = colours[Math.floor(colours.length * Math.random())];
    links[a].style.color = randomColour;
}
```

To minimize the delay between setting the color, and parsing the link, bind a `DOMContentLoaded` event, or simply paste the code at the end of the `<body>`:

http://jsfiddle.net/V6Chb/1/

```
<a>Test</a>
  ... 
<a>Test</a>
<script>
(function() { // <-- Anonymous function to not leak variables to the global scope
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName('a');
    var colours = ["green", "red", "blue"];
    for (var a = 0; a < links.length; a++) {
        var randomColour = colours[Math.floor(colours.length * Math.random())];
        links[a].style.color = randomColour;
    }
})();
```

Comment: Contrary to what you claim, this does not *ensure* that each link gets a different color. A better way could be to shuffle the color array. Of course if there are more links than colors, you cannot assign a unique color anyway.... just saying :)

Comment: @FelixKling Each link gets one of the colors in the array: http://jsfiddle.net/V6Chb/. So, when the array contains "red" and "green", and this code is used on a page with, say, 1000 links, then at least one link is red, and at least one is green (in most cases).

Comment: Yes, I understand... I was just referring to your statement *ensure that each link gets a different color*. It can still be that every link gets the same color or at least two links share the same color, so not every link gets a different color. A better statement might be *to ensure that every link gets a **random** color*. Anyways, it's not a big deal, no hard feelings.

Comment: @RobW apart from putting this code in the <head> how do i ensure that all the lists are coloured before the page loads? At the moment there is a slight delay between the anchors loading and then being coloured.

Comment: @Harry Either bind a `DOMContentLoaded` event, or put the script at the end of the `<body>`. See the example in my answer.

Comment: @RobW Thanks! I've got it to work using `DOMContentLoaded`. JS code: http://jsfiddle.net/bTW93/

Comment: @Harry Here's your demo with links to check whether anything happens ;) http://jsfiddle.net/bTW93/1/